# I am trying to pass a lambda as argument

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, std-function

Trying to pass a lambda to a constructor:

```
#include <functional>
#include <exception> 

template<typename R>
class Nisse
{
    private:
        Nisse(Nisse const&)             = delete;
        Nisse(Nisse&&)                  = delete;
        Nisse& operator=(Nisse const&)  = delete;
        Nisse& operator=(Nisse&&)       = delete;
    public:
        Nisse(std::function<R> const& func) {}
};

int main()
{
    Nisse<int>   nisse([](){return 5;});
}
```

When I compile I get an error message:

```
Test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Test.cpp:19:39: error: no matching function for call to ‘Nisse<int>::Nisse(main()::<lambda()>)’
Test.cpp:19:39: note: candidate is:
Test.cpp:14:9: note: Nisse<R>::Nisse(const std::function<R>&) [with R = int]
Test.cpp:14:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘main()::<lambda()>’ to ‘const std::function<int>&’
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of the template arg to `std::function` is wrong. Try using

```
Nisse(std::function<R()> const& func) {}
```

Specifically, the template argument needs to be a function type, but all you were passing was the desired return type.

Comment: Thanks. Still geting me teeth in C++11